# Composition over inheritance - How to make components extensible?

Tags: c#, inheritance, components

Due to be being stung by a multiple/diamond inheritance issue with my code, I have been attempting to learn and switch to more of a composition pattern.

Despite my best efforts, I'm not really 'getting it' as it pertains to my code. Instead of having everything in a base class, I have been trying to think of behaviours that can be split off into other components.

The problem is I don't know to make the class or components extensible.

This is an example of my code...

```
public class SelectList : BaseControl
{
    private ISelectListActions SelectActions { get; }

    public string Text {
        get { return SelectActions.Text; }
    }

    public SelectList(IWebDriver driver, By locator, ISelectListActions selectActions) : base(driver, locator)
    {
        SelectActions = selectActions;
    }

    public void SelectByText(string text)
    {
        SelectActions.SelectByText(text);
    }
}
```

`SelectActions` is designed to be my component representing all behaviours (all grouped together for this example).

Let's say I want to extend the functionality of the `SelectList` class by adding a new method called `CheckText`.

The traditional inheritance solution would look something like this....

```
public class BetterSelectList : SelectList
{
    public BetterSelectList(IWebDriver driver, By locator, ISelectListActions selectActions) : base(driver, locator, selectActions) { }

    public void CheckText()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CheckText");
    }
}
```

But what if I end up needing to do that another 5 times - I'll end up in an inheritance rabbit hole again.

I can't figure out the composition solution:

If I add the new `CheckText` method to `ISelectListActions` and provide a concrete implementation, I will need to expose it in `SelectList` if I want to use it from an instance of `SelectList`. Then every instance of `SelectList` will expose that method which I might not necessarily want.

Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: For the example you're giving, extension methods would work quite well. If you need to get more complex functionality in your extensions the decorator pattern might help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this but not sure this will help or not

```
abstract class Action
    {
        public void Perform(SelectList list)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("CheckText");
        }
    }

class CheckBoxAction1:Action
{
    public void Perform(SelectList list)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("CheckText1");
    }
}

class CheckBoxAction2:Action
{
    public void Perform(SelectList list)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("CheckText2");
    }
}
class ComposedActions{
    private Action _action;
    public ComposedActions(Action action)
    { 
      _action=action;
    }
    public void Perform(SelectList list)
    {
      _action.Perform(list);
    }
 }
ComposedActions action1= new ComposedActions(new CheckBoxAction1());
ComposedActions action2= new ComposedActions(new CheckBoxAction2());
SelectList list = new SelectList();
action1.Perform(list);
//CheckText1
action2.Perform(list);
//CheckText2
```